Is it possible to subscribe to my pull requests check results in Slack
Is it possible to receive notifications in Slack (or at least by email) of required checks run results when I create/update the PR?
I guess the command should be something like
/github subscribe <repo> workflows:{ event:"..." ... }

I cannot find this in GitHub docs.
I tried different commands for Slack bot, neither resulted in any notification.

Perhaps using Github WebHooks?

I'd like to get notifications in Slack
